# Websocket channel listening to same message multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

Trying to create a chat application. I'm able to send and listen to the messages sent on the websocket.

The listen stream listens for any data incoming and appends it to the List which I'm using to manage the chat of the widget.

I'm using listview.builder which uses the list length and changes state of the list to show new messages.

I'm a bit confused if the websocket if listening to the same messages multiple times or the listview.builder is building the widget the amount of times length of message list is.

I'm using Django channels for websocket and print the number of messages sent is proper so nothing on server side for sure.

ERROR: -
For example
on 1st message, I see 1 message
on 2nd message, I see 2 messages being built
on 3rd message, I see 3 messages being built
... and so on.

Websocket code

```
class NotificationController {
  static final NotificationController _singleton =
      NotificationController._internal();

  StreamController<String> streamController =
      StreamController.broadcast(sync: true);

  IOWebSocketChannel? channel;
  late var channelStream = channel?.stream.asBroadcastStream();

  factory NotificationController() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  NotificationController._internal() {
    initWebSocketConnection();
  }

  initWebSocketConnection() async {
    var storedUserInfo = storage.getUserInfoStorage();
    Map storedData = await storedUserInfo;
    String userID = storedData['user_id'];


    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        Uri.parse('ws://192.168.1.109:8001/chat/$userID/'),
        pingInterval: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return await initWebSocketConnection();
    }

    print("socket connection initializied");
    channel?.sink.done.then((dynamic _) => _onDisconnected());

  }


  //int i = 0;

  void sendMessage(messageObject, Function messageListener) {
    try {
      channelStream?.listen((data) {
        //i += 1;
        Map _message = json.decode(data);
        messageListener(_message);
      });
      channel?.sink.add(json.encode(messageObject));
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _onDisconnected() {
    initWebSocketConnection();
  }
}
```

Lisview.builder code

```
  List<ChatMessage> messages = [];

  void messageListener(Map message) {
    setState(() {
      messages.add(
          ChatMessage(message: message['message'], toUser: message['to_user']));
    });
  }




ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemCount: messages.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 14,
            right: 14,
            top: 10,
            bottom: 10,
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color:
                  messages[index].toUser == widget.userUid
                      ? Colors.greenAccent
                      : Colors.blue,
            ),
            alignment:
                messages[index].toUser == widget.userUid
                    ? Alignment.bottomRight
                    : Alignment.topLeft,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text(
              messages[index].message as String,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }),
```

Comment: have you solved the problem? if so share it with us!